# JS closes Tab on Laptop, but whole browser on mobile -

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

```
<a href="JavaScript:window.close()">Close</a>
```

This simply code, that I use a lot...closes ONLY THE tab on laptop (which is the action I want) but it closes THE WHOLE browser on phone ...both laptop and phone are using Chrome browser.  So my users on phone are being brought back to phone screen and required to pick a browser and log in to the site again.

Is there a better way to close a window with a button that might work more consistently across platforms? MY particular button is on a jquery mobile "data-role=header" and so here's the entire piece of code.

---

```
<div data-role="header">
<a href="JavaScript:page.close()">Close</a>

<h3>Check In Summary - <%=now%></h3> 

<a href="admin-info.asp" target="_blank" data-ajax="false" data-icon="gear" data-ajax="false" data-iconpos="left">Admin</a>

</div>
```

Comment: This does sound like a bug in the phone browser. `window.close` is supposed to close only the current browsing context.

Comment: That's what I was thinking,  I'm going to go check a few other mobile browsers and see what happens.  Thanks.  And thanks @qwertynl for corrected my "yelling" - I didn't even realize I was doing it !

Comment: Happy to help @user3092340 :-D

Comment: Do you have multiple tabs open in your mobile browser? If not, this behaves the same way on mobile and on desktop - closing the one and only open tab exits the browser.

Comment: I thought that at first too (single tab only) but I tested it with multiple tabs and it did the same ....however I did just test it on Safari/Mobile and it worked the way we expect it to...so it does seem to be a bug in the Chrome browser on my iPhone.   Going to see if I need a new version of it, and if not, I'll tell Google.  Thanks to everyone who took time to ponder.